# Kendo UI grid toolbar template Dropdown selector Error (textbox instead of dropdown)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

[Example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/toolbar-template.html)
I've been looking into getting this to work but so far instead of a dropdown I get and empty textbox which doesn't do anything.

Below is my present code:-

```
@section js {
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <label class="category-label" for="external">Show checks by ex:</label>
        <input type="search" id="external" style="width: 230px"></input>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theGrid;
    $().ready(function () {
        $('#listDiv').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: 'json',
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("_IList", "Entry", new { @ExId = Model.ExId })',
                        data: { ignore: Math.random() }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: 'Id',
                        fields: {
                            Id: { type: 'number' },
                            Name: { type: 'string' },
                            Ex: { type: 'string' },
                            Date: { type: 'string' },
                            Check1: { type: 'string' },
                            Check2: { type: 'string' },
                            Check3: { type: 'string' },
                            Check4: { type: 'string' },
                            Check5: { type: 'string' },
                            Edit: { type: 'string' }
                        }
                    },
                    data: "Data",
                    total: "Count"
                }
            },
            scrollable: false,
            toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
            columns:
                [
                    {
                        field: 'Name'
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'Ex'
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'Date'
                    },
                    {
                        template: '#=Template1#' + sitePath + '#=Patient1#',
                        field: 'Patient1',
                        title: 'Patient 1',
                        width: 50
                    },
                    {
                        template: '#=Template2#' + sitePath + '#=Patient2#',
                        field: 'Patient2',
                        title: 'Patient 2',
                        width: 50
                    },
                    {
                        template: '#=Template3#' + sitePath + '#=Patient3#',
                        field: 'Patient3',
                        title: 'Patient 3',
                        width: 50
                    },
                    {
                        template: '#=Template4#' + sitePath + '#=Patient4#',
                        field: 'Patient4',
                        title: 'Patient 4',
                        width: 50
                    },
                    {
                        template: '#=Template5#' + sitePath + '#=Patient5#',
                        field: 'Patient5',
                        title: 'Patient 5',
                        width: 50
                    }

                ],
            pageable: true
        });
        var dropDown = grid.find("#external").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "ExName",
            dataValueField: "ExId",
            autoBind: false,
            optionLabel: "All",
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                severFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("_Ex", "Entry")',
                    data: { ignore: Math.random() }
                }
            },
            change: function () {
                var value = this.value();
                if (value) {
                    grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({ field: "ExId", operator: "eq", value: parseString(value) });
                } else {
                    grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
                }
            }
        });
        theGrid = $('#listDiv').data('kendoGrid');
    });        
</script>
<style scoped="scoped">
    #grid .k-toolbar
    {
        min-height: 27px;
    }
    .external-label
    {
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-right: .5em;
    }
    #external
    {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .toolbar {
        float: right;
        margin-right: .8em;
    }
</style>
}
<h2>Check Lists</h2>

<div id="listDiv"></div>
<br />
```

It works to display all check lists for each Ex which I can select on a previous page and pass in the string Id to this one but I'd like to be able to figure out what's wrong with with the toolbar template as having the functionality on 1 page rather than spread over 2 is far more desirable.

Any help/guidance will be much appreciated.

Edit:

I did also find someone else who encountered the problem except they didn't get a forum response.
[Example 2](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/dropdownlist-in-toolbar-showing-as-a-text-box-so-doesn-t-work.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that somebody else encountered the problem and didn't receive a response, however the linked forum thread does contain a response and an answer to this issue. In that particular case a Javascript error had occurred on the page which prevented the dropdown from initializing correctly and I believe this is also the case for yourself.

Although not completely working because there isn't a valid datasource, I took your example code and dumped it into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nukefusion/BXxGS/) and (after fixing some JS errors) you can see that the dropdown appears absolutely fine.

In particular, there were errors regarding `grid` and `sitePath` not being defined that prevented the dropdown from initializing.

```
    var grid;
    var sitePath = '';
    $().ready(function () {
        grid = $('#listDiv').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: 'json',
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '',
                        data: { ignore: Math.random() }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: 'Id',
                        fields: {
                            Id: { type: 'number' },
                            Name: { type: 'string' },
                            Ex: { type: 'string' },
                            Date: { type: 'string' },
                            Check1: { type: 'string' },
                            Check2: { type: 'string' },
                            Check3: { type: 'string' },
                            Check4: { type: 'string' },
                            Check5: { type: 'string' },
                            Edit: { type: 'string' }
                        }
                    },
                    data: "Data",
                    total: "Count"
                }
            },
            scrollable: false,
            toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
            columns:
                [
                    {
                        field: 'Name'
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'Ex'
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'Date'
                    },
                    {
                        template: '#=Template1#' + sitePath + '#=Patient1#',
                        field: 'Patient1',
                        title: 'Patient 1',
                        width: 50
                    },
                    {
                        template: '#=Template2#' + sitePath + '#=Patient2#',
                        field: 'Patient2',
                        title: 'Patient 2',
                        width: 50
                    },
                    {
                        template: '#=Template3#' + sitePath + '#=Patient3#',
                        field: 'Patient3',
                        title: 'Patient 3',
                        width: 50
                    },
                    {
                        template: '#=Template4#' + sitePath + '#=Patient4#',
                        field: 'Patient4',
                        title: 'Patient 4',
                        width: 50
                    },
                    {
                        template: '#=Template5#' + sitePath + '#=Patient5#',
                        field: 'Patient5',
                        title: 'Patient 5',
                        width: 50
                    }

                ],
            pageable: true
        });
        var dropDown = grid.find("#external").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "ExName",
            dataValueField: "ExId",
            autoBind: false,
            optionLabel: "All",
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                severFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("_Ex", "Entry")',
                    data: { ignore: Math.random() }
                }
            },
            change: function () {
                var value = this.value();
                if (value) {
                    grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({ field: "ExId", operator: "eq", value: parseString(value) });
                } else {
                    grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
                }
            }
        });
        theGrid = $('#listDiv').data('kendoGrid');
    });
```

Comment: The response they got didn't answer the question but instead said that the answer was in the support ticket response which ofc isn't public hence no response as no solution was provided on that forum.  I'll look into testing your code tomorrow when I get into work.

Comment: The public forum does mention that other Javascript errors in the page were to blame, I believe that could also be your issue. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: I just finished testing it and with changing ($('#listDiv').kendoGrid({) to be (grid = $('#listDiv').kendoGrid({) it now shows the dropdown but I can't get the drop down to work because of some kendo script error = TypeError: r is undefined
kendo.web.min.js
Line 13

Comment: I would double check your datasource configuration for the dropdown. Check that there is a route for the action you are providing and that it successfully returns some data.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make it that far as I put a break point on the controller action which isn't reached at any point and it's setup exactly the same as the main grid datasource which uses the same datasource/action on another page in a hierarchy grid which works so I know it's not the action.  I'd imagine it has to be with how the dropdown is setup or I've no clue.

Comment: I'm gona mark this as correct answer and start a new question about why the dropdown doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410900/kendo-ui-grid-toolbar-template-dropdown-error  here's the link if you have any other ideas about the new issue.